# NSTableView Not Retaining NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

This is a very simple `NSTableView` with 1 column and rows consisting of `NSTableCellViews` that display a simple string and which I am setting up programmatically (no nib/interface builder).

**I cannot get the tableview to display the strings and cannot figure out why?! And when I catch the row selection event after the table is displayed the cell object is nil?!**

I must be doing something incredibly stupid, but I can't see it. Any thoughts?

```
@implementation PreferencesSelectorPanel
-(id)initWithWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

        _preferenceTypes = @[@"Settings 1", @"Settings 2", @"Settings 3", @"Settings 4", @"Settings 5"];

        _tv = [NSTableView new];
        _tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _tv.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        _tv.focusRingType = NSFocusRingTypeNone;
        _tv.delegate = self;
        _tv.dataSource = self;
        _tv.rowHeight = 40;
        _tv.headerView = nil;
        _tv.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular;
        _tv.allowsColumnReordering = NO;
        _tv.allowsColumnResizing = NO;
        _tv.allowsEmptySelection = NO;
        _tv.allowsTypeSelect = NO;
        _tv.gridStyleMask = NSTableViewSolidHorizontalGridLineMask;//NSTableViewGridNone;

        NSTableColumn *col1 = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"c1"];
        col1.resizingMask = NSTableColumnAutoresizingMask;
        [_tv addTableColumn:col1];

        [self addSubview:_tv];

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[_tv(200)]-(>=10)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tv)]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(10)-[_tv]-(10)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tv)]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tv
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInTableView");
    return _preferenceTypes.count;
}

-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tc row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSTextField *tf = [NSTextField 
    labelWithString:_preferenceTypes[row]];
    tf.textColor = [NSColor blackColor];

    NSTableCellView *cell = [NSTableCellView new];
    cell.textField = tf;

    NSLog(@"Row for row %d with label:%@",(int)row, cell.textField.stringValue);
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSTableCellView *cell = _tv.selectedCell;
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.textField.stringValue);
}
@end
```

This is what gets logged to the console. I've been wanking around on this for hours now and getting no where:

```
2018-05-11 numberOfRowsInTableView
2018-05-11 Row for row 0 with label:Settings 1
2018-05-11 Row for row 1 with label:Settings 2
2018-05-11 Row for row 2 with label:Settings 3
2018-05-11 Row for row 3 with label:Settings 4
2018-05-11 Row for row 4 with label:Settings 5
2018-05-11 (null)
2018-05-11 (null)
2018-05-11 (null)
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: `cell.textField = tf;` does not add `tf` to `cell` as a subview.

Comment: Why not, it's declared like so in the NSTableViewCell source: 
@property (nullable, assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField; But I did find out I can simply return the NSTextField as the Cell rather than an NSTableViewCelll object and it works.

Comment: You have to add `tf` to `cell` as a subview: `[cell addSubview:tf]`.

Comment: @Willeke when you do that you can't easily control vertical alignment. Simpler to create a Cell based on NSView that has exactly what is required and no more or less.

Comment: Add constraints if you want to control allignment.

Comment: @Willeke well you could, but why? At that point you might as well write a simply NSView based control that behaves exactly the way you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to figure out what exactly the issue was. I arrived at several alternative solutions:

1. It is possible to simply return an NSTextField from `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`
2. It is also possible to add the NSTextField as a subView to the `NSTableCellView` but by doing that you have less control over layout.
3. It possible to create any custom control based on NSView.

I opted for the last and created a custom NSView that looked and behaved exactly like I wanted. This is what I did.

```
@interface PreferenceTableViewCell : NSView
@property (nonnull, strong, readonly) NSTextField *tf;
@end

@implementation PreferenceTableViewCell
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        _tf = [NSTextField labelWithString:@""];
        _tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _tf.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        [self addSubview:_tf];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[_tf]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tf)]];
        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    }
    return self;
 }
 @end
```

Comment: Do you mean `NSTextField` instead of `NSTextView`? Why do you wrap the text field in a view?

Comment: You are correct, typo fixed. I wrapped the NSTextField in a view so that I could control vertical alignement. The NSTableView documentation suggests that NSView based cells are the way to go, so I created a simple one that behaved exactly as I wanted. When I tried returning an unwrapped NSTextField from the delegate and/or adding it as a subview to NSTableCellView, I was unable to easily control vertical alignment within the space allotted to the row.